# How to get User()->id in Controllers (Laravel 8+)

Tags: laravel, authentication, userid

I am trying to select tasks by **user('id')**, but I can't get it in a **Controller**, where I selecting data from **DB**.
I have tried many thing and some of them from **stackoverflow**, but it isn't working.

I tried:

```
1. $userId = Auth::check() ? Auth::id() : true;
2. Auth::user()->id;
3. public function getUserId(){
   
   on Model} - and then get this value on Controllers
```

and some other things

I have the simplest code:

1. I installed registration: npm artisan ui --auth something like that
2. I installed vuejs (on Laravel)
3. I created api on Laravel, and some logic on vue

I didn't touch "**app.blade.php**" it's the same as it was.

I can get data, user: name, id and all what I want in file "**app.blade.php**" but I need those data in **folder->file**: **App\Http\Controllers{{SomeController}}**, but I don't know how.

Was someone in this situation?
How can I get user id in Controllers?

Thanks guys for earlier.

Comment: use `\Auth::guard('web')->user();`

Comment: And I forgot. When I trying check the registration like: Auth::check() in the Controller, I have false, but I logged in.

Comment: If you suggested use this code instead of: Auth::id() of Auth::user()->id then it's not working or I missing something.

Answer (score 16):

If you need user id, just use one of this :

```
auth()->id();
```

using Auth facade's

```
\Auth::id();
```

or, using Request instance

```
$request->user()->id
```

Follow this simple controller code, i showed 3 different way here :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class SomeController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function getUserId(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user(); // Retrieve the currently authenticated user...
        $id = Auth::id(); // Retrieve the currently authenticated user's ID...

        
        $user = $request->user(); // returns an instance of the authenticated user...
        $id = $request->user()->id; // Retrieve the currently authenticated user's ID...

        
        $user = auth()->user(); // Retrieve the currently authenticated user...
        $id = auth()->id();  // Retrieve the currently authenticated user's ID...
    }
}
```

Comment: I have 2 guards 1) user 2) admin. If both or any of them are logged in then how can I get the logged in front user or admin user information? `auth()->guard('admin')->email()` not working. Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
Auth::user()->id;
```

This should work if you have Auth middleware on that controller method where you try to get it, please check do you added that middleware.
For checking you can use `php arisan route:list` command.

Comment: Yes, I have auth in column "Middleware" when I checked like you said through command php artisan route:list.

Comment: When I trying Auth::user()->id; Laravel saying that "id" isn't available in Auth.

Comment: @K.Igor What is of output of \Auth::user() ?

Comment: If I output in "app.blade.php" then it returns Array with user data. If I try to get data from Auth::user() from controller to vuejs and on console.log() then I get object with back request, like: headers, status, statusText and so on...

Comment: I've tried output "Auth::user()" throught Route and Controller on a page and it's showed empty.

Answer (score 1):

Is someone still searching an answer on this question. I have some explanation how can you do this.

**Laravel** has a **Router** which routes authorization process through that **Controller** which you want, so you should redirect that process on your **Router** and in **Controller** create **constructor** which allows you to take **user id**.

**How can you do that?:**

**1**. First of all you should find **Controller** and **Route** which responsible for authorization and registration users.
In my case it was:
a)**App\Http\Controllers\HomeController**
b)**routes\web.php**

**2**. Second, you should redirect your authorization **Router** to the **Controller** where you trying to get **Auth::id()**;
In my case it was:
**App\Http\Controllers\TasksController**

so, in **routes\web.php** I did this:

```
    //was
Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
    //was
    Auth::routes();
    //was
    Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
    //added
    Auth::routes();
    //added
    Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\TasksController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

perhaps you should have **index function** on that **controller**

**3**. Third you should add **constructor** in your **controller** where you want to get **user id**, this **constructor** I took from **HomeController**, it already was there.
In my case it was:

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
```

code with function on my **TasksController**:

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
       
    public function index()
    {              
        $userId = Auth::check() ? Auth::id() : true;       
    }
```

And now I can take user id.
PS: **constructor I added on the top in class TasksController in Controller**