# Auth - get model

Tags: laravel

After using the `Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable` trait on a model, I can now do `Auth::id()` in places in my app (when the current auth-ed thing is that particular model).

Is there a way to get the class / type of the auth-ed model?

Perhaps something like `Auth::model()` which might return the model's class name (such as App\Models\User or App\Models\MyCustomAuthCapabaleModel)?

Comment: Please share more details. Which trait do you use **exactly**?

Comment: @NicoHaase `Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable` - I don't know for a fact that it provides the feature I'm asking for, though. I was just stating that I used it to be able to do Auth::id(). The main question is - is there a way to get the auth-ed model.

Comment: That trait does not contain an `id()` method in Laravel 8 or 9. Can you share more details about how you use that trait?

Comment: Also, does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64787214/how-to-get-user-id-in-controllers-laravel-8 help?

Comment: Are you looking for `Auth::user()` ?

Comment: @NicoHaase - doing `Auth::id()` calls `getAuthIdentifier()` on that trait.

Comment: @Techno - yes you're right, that does it (well adding `::class` to the end of your snippet anyway). I guess I overlooked it as I was looking for something more generic than the word `user`. Perhaps I've misunderstood that the `Authenticatable` was designed to be used with 'things' that represent 'things' other than only users.

Comment: @NicoHaase - re that other linked questions - kind of, but I think I would've still inadvertently overlooked it as per my other comment above.

Comment: @Dan. Thanks for letting us know! I've added an answer to the question with a little explaination for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Auth::user();` returns the model of the logged in user.

If you ever wish to change the `User` model, you can change it in `config/auth.php` at the key `providers.users.model`

Comment: I didn't have to add anything to the config file to make Auth::user() work with other models, but looks like I might need to look into / address the config file thing to make other things work.

Comment: I'm sorry if my wording is unclear. I meant to say that it returns the model listed in your config. If at any point in time you wish to change the `User` model, you can change it here. `Auth::user()` should then return the new class :)

Comment: You may also use `auth()->user()`

Answer (score 0):

`Auth::user();` returns all the information about the authenticated user

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm going to have to give the points the person who helped out in the comments!